# How do i allow my Jslider to fit inside my JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jslider

I am programming a small application and have run into a big bump. I am stuck on why the JSlider won't allow me to add it to the JPanel. 
When the last line of code reads:

"add.(slider);"

the JSlider covers the entire JPanel. Is this correct and I need to resize my JSlider somehow? Or, have I made a mistake with the code and are not making the Jslider visible within the Jpanel?

Here's my code:

```
package atmosfile;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JSlider;


import java.awt.*;

public class Main extends JFrame {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


 public Main() {

     super("Package Choice");
     setSize(800, 600);
     setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
     setLocationRelativeTo(null);

       JPanel panel = new JPanel();

         panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(1, 100, 500));
         panel.add(new JButton("Package 1"));
         panel.add(new JButton("Package 2"));
         panel.add(new JButton("Package 3"));
         add(panel);

       JSlider slider = new JSlider();   

         slider.setLayout(new FlowLayout(1, 100, 200));
         slider.setMajorTickSpacing(5);
         slider.setPaintTicks(true);
         slider.setSize(200, 200);
         slider.setVisible(true);
         panel.add(slider);


        }    
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help its most appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

The horizontal gap of your `FlowLayout` is so large that it "pushes" the `JSlider` component out of the drawable area of the frame. Reducing it brings it back in into view again. Also would recommend avoiding the use of magic numbers (1 = `FlowLayout.CENTER`):

```
panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 50, 500));
```

Comment: +1, especially for the magic number part. Why would anybody even look at the source code to found out what the magic number is for CENTER?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have changed the magic number and put the JSliders size well within the frame, although this does not seem to be working. The size is not actually altering even when I change the numbers. Could this be because I have put:
slider.setSize(80, 200); rather than setPreferredSize?
Sorry if any mistakes seem obvious, I'm still new to this.

Comment: If you're not seeing any change, try cleaning your project. Also `setSize` will have no effect on the `JSlider` size. You would need to override `getPreferredSize` for the component.